# TestNG execution by methods as well as groups

Tags: java, testng

I like to execute my tests filtered by methods as well as groups. Is that possible in TestNG?

For example. I have below two TestNG classes with two methods.

```
Class - SampleJ1
Methods - Test1(group=sanity), Test2(group=regression), Test3, Test4, Test5
Class - SampleJ2
Methods - Test1(group=sanity), Test2(group=regression), Test3, Test4, Test5
```

My automation framework generates TestNG XML file. If I create XML file with below data, it should execute only sanity group of mentioned methods.

```
<groups>
  <run>
    <include name="sanity" />
  </run>
</groups>
<test thread-count="12" name="Browser">
  <classes>
    <class name="SampleJ1">
      <include method="Test1"/>
      <include method="Test2"/>
      <include method="Test3"/>
      <include method="Test4"/>
    </class>
    <class name="SampleJ2">
      <include method="Test1"/>
      <include method="Test2"/>
      <include method="Test3"/>
      <include method="Test4"/>
    </class>
  </classes>
</test>
```

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Your current suite file is including everything, so everything will be run.

Comment: Ya. Actually it will execute whatever the methods I included. OR, it will execute what ever the groups I mentioned. My question is, Is there a way to to mix both? Here in this example, I like to execute only the group sanity for the methods I included.

Comment: @Jeyabal, do you use Maven?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz. Yes am using Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to filter test methods to execute by their names and groups they belong to.
Firstly, there is no special solution for this in pure TestNG (otherwise some TestNG experts like @juherr would have answered). Skipping test methods with an implementation of the `InvokedMethodListener` would leave logs you probably do not want.

I see two options.

In the first one you could implement a `@Factory` method that could instantiate your test classes with `Set<Method>` or `Set<String>` as a constructor's parameter. In each of your test classes you would check whether the method to be executed (or its `String` representation) is in the `Set`. `@Before` annotated or `beforeInvocation` methods would handle the logic whether or not given method will be executed. Additionally, your `testng.xml` would specify `<groups>` elements to run. Again this may have the drawback of leaving `Skipped: x` in your logs and reports.

The second option would be to make good use of Maven together with its [Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). (If you do not use any build tool like Gradle or Maven, then I'm sure you should try). When you test with Maven, you can specify which groups and which test methods have to be executed.
Your `pom.xml` should be much like the following:

```
<!-- modelVersion, groupId, etc. -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- (...) -->
    </plugins>
    <!-- (...) -->
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- (...) -->
</dependencies>
```

Say, you have a test class like that:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Test(groups = {"firstGroup"})
    public void firstMethod(Method method) {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }

    @Test(groups = {"secondGroup"})
    public void secondMethod(Method method) {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }

    @Test(groups = {"secondGroup"})
    public void thirdMethod(Method method) {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }

    @Test(groups = {"secondGroup"})
    public void fourthMethod(Method method) {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }
}
```

In your `testng.xml` you can place the information, which groups to execute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite Name">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="secondGroup"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <test name="Default Test Name">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And then execute a Maven goal to decide which methods you execute:

```
mvn clean -Dtest=TestClass#thirdMethod+secondMethod test
```

Syntax for multiple methods and multiple classes can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html).
Output:

```
Running TestClass
secondMethod
thirdMethod
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

The fourth method has not been executed, even though it belongs to the `secondGroup`.
If there are many methods to execute, you may write a custom bash script for it.

It was not possible (at least for me) to filter groups with Maven and methods with TestNG.

Comment: Thank much for such a detailed explanation.